# Send iCalendar invitation in mail using groovy

Tags: email, grails, plugins, groovy, icalendar

How can i send **icalendar** invitation in mail using **grails**. There is a plugin available named '**ic-alendar:0.4.0**' for it, but i can't find any solution how to use this plugins to send mail using **grails mail API**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the icalendar plugin to create a calendar invitation as a String, turn this into a byte[] then attach this as a file to the mail plugin.

Here's a method I use to generate the attachment as a byte[] (I have a concept of a Game for my app [SquadPoint.com](http://www.squadpoint.com), so I pass this in to encapsulate setting relevant data on the invitation):

```
import ch.silviowangler.groovy.util.builder.ICalendarBuilder
//...

/**
 * Create a calendar event for sending with an email as a .ics attachment
 * @param game
 * @param timeZoneId
 * @return
 */
byte[] calendarEventAsBytes(Game game, timeZoneId) {
    def organiserName = getOrganiserName(game)
    def organiserEmail = getOrganiserEmail(game)

    def builder = new ICalendarBuilder()
    builder.calendar {
        events {
            event( start:    game.dateTime, 
                   end:      game.dateTime.plusHours(1), 
                   summary:  "Game ${game.venue ? 'at ' + game.venue : ''}",
                   timezone: timeZoneId) {

                organizer(name: organiserName, email: organiserEmail)
            }
        }
    }

    builder.cal.toString().getBytes('UTF-8')
}
```

Then to send it attached to an email:

```
def sendOutTeams(Game game) {

    // some set up..

    sesMail {

        to email
        subject "${organiserName} has selected teams (via Squadpoint.com)"
        html groovyPageRenderer.render(template: '/email-templates/canYouPlay', model: emailModel)
        attach "game.ics", "text/calendar", calendarEventAsBytes(game, timeZoneId)
    }
}
```

I use the AWS plugin to use SES to send my emails (hence the sesMail config closure), but should be pretty similar with the regular Grails Mail plugin, something like:

```
sendMail {
   multipart true
   to email
   subject "a subject"
   body "test"
   attach "game.ics", "text/calendar", calendarEventAsBytes(game, timeZoneId)
}
```

Comment: He can u tell me how did u take the input from the view and what did u do in the controller to extract the information and store it in the database. I guess the things are similar to the multipart request where we take the file as input and then extract the byte file to store it in the database. Can u please make ht things more clear.

Comment: This question isn't about storing things in the database, it's about sending an email with an icalendar attachment.